# While compiling frontend it compile also a .test.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, frontend

I've created a .test.js file in React with jest in which I test my component, that needs 2 props (a function and a state). The test is ok, it passes, but if I compile my frontend with npm run start_windows, it goes inside my file .test.js that I want to exclude from the compiling.

Otherwise, it displays an error for variables not defined inside the test.

Here's my code of the .test.js file.

```
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import Teleletture from "../directory";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });


it("Teleletture renders correctly", () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(
      <Teleletture
        handleChangeShownOut={function handleChangeShownOut() {
          if (isShown.output == true) {
            setIsShown({ ...isShown, output: false });
          } else {
            setIsShown({ ...isShown, output: true });
          }
        }}
        isShown={{
          algoritmo: false,
          output: false,
        }}
      />
    )
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
    Array [
      <div
        style={
          Object {
            "borderColor": "#c9c9c9",
            "borderRadius": "5px",
            "borderStyle": "solid",
            "height": "100%",
            "verticalAlign": "middle",
            "width": "100%",
          }
        }
      >
        <div>
          [...]
      </div>,
    ]
  `);
});
```

and that's my package-json.

```
{
  "name": "portale-zeus",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/x-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.35",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^25.1.0",
    "amazon-cognito-auth-js": "^1.3.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.26.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.23",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "convert-csv-to-json": "^1.0.0",
    "csv": "^5.3.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "json-to-txt": "^2.1.1",
    "jsoneditor": "^9.5.3",
    "jsoneditor-react": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-color-palette": "^5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.2.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-json-editor-viewer": "^1.0.7",
    "react-jwt": "^1.0.8",
    "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-select": "^4.2.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.4",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "use-state-with-callback": "^2.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8080 env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts start",
    "start_windows": "set PORT=8080 && env-cmd -f .env.local react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --watchAll",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-dev": "env-cmd -f .env.dev react-scripts build",
    "build-prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

The error instead is:

```
Failed to compile.

src\tests\Teleletture.test.js
  Line 20:15:  'isShown' is not defined     no-undef   
  Line 21:13:  'setIsShown' is not defined  no-undef   
  Line 21:29:  'isShown' is not defined     no-undef   
  Line 23:13:  'setIsShown' is not defined  no-undef   
  Line 23:29:  'isShown' is not defined     no-undef   

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

My goal is to exlude the .test.js files from compiling in frontend execution, or in second place to avoid the error that I get while compiling.